# Finding amount of sequence matches per line

Tags: unix, grep

I'm looking to use GREP or something similiar to find the total matches of a 5 letter sequence (AATTC) in every line of a file, and then print the result in a new file.  For example:

```
File 1:
GGGGGAATTCGAATTC
GGGGGAATTCGGGGGG
GGGGGAATTCCAATTC
```

Then in another file it prints the matches line by line

```
File 2:
2
1
2
```

Comment: please add code you tried to question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '{ print gsub(/AATTC/,"") }' file1 > file2
```

> The **`gsub()`** function returns the number of substitutions made

---

```
$ cat file2
2
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use `grep`, then put that in a while loop,

```
$ while read -r line; do grep -o 'AATTC'<<<"$line"|wc -l >> file2 ; done < file1
$ cat file2
2
1
2
```

Another way: using `perl`.

```
$ perl -ne 'print s/AATTC/x/g ."\n"' file1 > file2
```